# nlog Logging Map using VB.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, logging, nlog

I used **nlog** in my `C#` project and it's working as charm, but now I need to use it in `VB.NET` project and when I convert the code I keep getting this Error:

```
Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Info' accepts this number of arguments.  
Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Debug' accepts this number of arguments.  
Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Error' accepts this number of arguments.  
Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Fatal' accepts this number of arguments.  
Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Warn' accepts this number of arguments.
```

**This is my `C#` Code :**

```
private static readonly Logger ClassLogger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
private static readonly Lazy<Dictionary<TraceLevel, Action<string>>> LoggingMap = new Lazy<Dictionary<TraceLevel, Action<string>>>(() => new Dictionary<TraceLevel, Action<string>> { { TraceLevel.Info, ClassLogger.Info }, { TraceLevel.Debug, ClassLogger.Debug }, { TraceLevel.Error, ClassLogger.Error }, { TraceLevel.Fatal, ClassLogger.Fatal }, { TraceLevel.Warn, ClassLogger.Warn } });

private Dictionary<TraceLevel, Action<string>> Logger
    {
        get { return LoggingMap.Value; }
    }
```

**and this is `VB.NET` version:**

```
Private Shared ReadOnly ClassLogger As Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()
Private Shared ReadOnly LoggingMap As New Lazy(Of Dictionary(Of TraceLevel, Action(Of String))) _
    (Function() New Dictionary(Of TraceLevel, Action(Of String)) From _
                {{TraceLevel.Info, ClassLogger.Info}, _
                {TraceLevel.Debug, ClassLogger.Debug}, _
                {TraceLevel.Error, ClassLogger.Error}, _
                {TraceLevel.Fatal, ClassLogger.Fatal}, _
                {TraceLevel.Warn, ClassLogger.Warn} _
            })
 Private ReadOnly Property Logger() As Dictionary(Of TraceLevel, Action(Of String))
        Get
            Return LoggingMap.Value
        End Get
    End Property
```

**Note** this Errors rise in `ClassLogger.Info` ...
Can any one help me to find way I'm getting this error.
thank you in advance.

Comment: You can follow this guide: https://brutaldev.com/post/logging-setup-in-5-minutes-with-nlog

Comment: Thank you @Hackerman but I'm letting changing the way i do it as last resort. if I fail to convert it to vb.

Comment: Maybe `{TraceLevel.Info, AddressOf ClassLogger.Info}, ...`, etc?

Comment: @Mark thank you , adding AddressOf fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VB.NET, you need to use the [`AddressOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y72ewk2b.aspx) operator to create a function delegate - [`Action(Of T)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is just a predefined delegate - so the code should look like:

```vb
Private Shared ReadOnly LoggingMap As New Lazy(Of Dictionary(Of TraceLevel, Action(Of String))) _
    (Function() New Dictionary(Of TraceLevel, Action(Of String)) From _
                {{TraceLevel.Info, AddressOf ClassLogger.Info}, _
                {TraceLevel.Debug, AddressOf ClassLogger.Debug}, _
                {TraceLevel.Error, AddressOf ClassLogger.Error}, _
                {TraceLevel.Fatal, AddressOf ClassLogger.Fatal}, _
                {TraceLevel.Warn, AddressOf ClassLogger.Warn} _
            })
```