# New lazy initialization

Tags: .net, vb.net, nlog

Attempting to create a logging helper class using NLog. But I am getting the following error when creating the property.

> Error BC30518 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New'
>   can be called with these arguments

```
Private Shared ReadOnly LoggingMap As New Lazy(Of Dictionary(Of TraceLevel, Action(Of String)))(Function() New Dictionary(Of TraceLevel, Action(Of String))() From {
            {TraceLevel.Info, ClassLogger.Info},
            {TraceLevel.Debug, ClassLogger.Debug},
            {TraceLevel.[Error], ClassLogger.[Error]},
            {TraceLevel.Fatal, ClassLogger.Fatal},
            {TraceLevel.Warn, ClassLogger.Warn}
})
```

I wish for it to be used as follows.

```
''' <summary>
''' Get property for Logger
''' </summary>
Private ReadOnly Property Logger() As Dictionary(Of TraceLevel, Action(Of String))
    Get
        Return LoggingMap.Value
    End Get
End Property
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer thanks for this: [nlog Logging Map using VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35013379/nlog-logging-map-using-vb-net)

```
    Private Shared ReadOnly LoggingMap As New Lazy(Of Dictionary(Of TraceLevel, Action(Of String))) _
(Function() New Dictionary(Of TraceLevel, Action(Of String)) From
            {{TraceLevel.Info, AddressOf ClassLogger.Info},
            {TraceLevel.Debug, AddressOf ClassLogger.Debug},
            {TraceLevel.Error, AddressOf ClassLogger.Error},
            {TraceLevel.Fatal, AddressOf ClassLogger.Fatal},
            {TraceLevel.Warn, AddressOf ClassLogger.Warn}
        })
```